# Is my wall pak after being exposed to waste-water?

Tags: fiqh, sunni, taharah

I used to have a problem with moisture developing on my bathroom wall.  According to the plumber, this was due to a leak in the waste-water pipe from the commode upstairs; the water would accumulate in the ceiling and eventually flow down the wall.

The plumber has sealed this leak and the wall has since been painted (it is not a plastic paint, it is more like whitewash).  The wall itself has long since dried from the initial leak, and I have noticed no further problems with moisture accumulating on it.  However, given that the wall had been exposed to waste-water for so long, I am concerned about whether or not the wall itself is still *najis*.

In particular, sometimes water from the shower will splash onto the wall, and then flow down (e.g. onto the knobs of my shower).  I can't even be sure that my *wudu* and *ghusl* are still valid in such a situation.

I am looking for answers from a Sunni perspective: **How should I consider my wall, and anything that comes in contact with it?  Is it *najis*, or is it *pak*?**

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we strongly suggest that you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I have severely overhauled this question for the sake of clarity.  Please review to ensure I have not misconstrued what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Wadu and Ghusal are ok. You do not need to worry about it. You said

- Your bathroom walls do not get wet anymore
- It has been painted and supposedly stays dry.
- I am assuming no smell comes from it

That means it is properly sealed and you can consider it clean, from outside.

It is very easy to detect bad smell if something is Najs (dirty). I think in your case, there is no bad smell that means, it is clean.

I had a similar situation where I would take extra care in shower where the water drop from body would fall back in bucket, making the bucket water unclean. Although i never asked question about it, I realized finally, it is OK. The water is still clean. So in this I would say do not bother.